# what are the features to add to a windows server in order to have the sound system?

Tags: audio, windows-server-2012, windows, windows-server-2016

I have some windows servers (2012 and 2016) where I would like the sound system working, so that I could watch a video with sound.

what is(are) the features that need to be installed?
[image]

Currently the sound services are there and started but still no sound.
what is missing?

[image]

a partial view of the device manager

[image]

These machines are Virtual and I don't have access to the host.

Comment: Does the server have an audio output device shown in Device Manager?

Comment: no, it doesn't - as per the picture added to the question now

Comment: Are these Physical or Virtual? If Physical are you sitting in front of them or connecting remotely. If Virtual are you using VM console or remote desktop?

Comment: These machines are Virtual and I don't have access to the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Remote Desktop Connection, you need to ensure that Local Resources > Remote Audio > Settings > Remote Audio Playback is set to Play on this computer.

On the server, you need to ensure that audio redirection is not disabled in group policy: Computer > Administrative Templates > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection > Allow audio and video playback redirection.